# Is the EM algorithm guaranteed to converge if the log likelihood is concave

Tags: maximum-likelihood, inference, optimization, factor-analysis, expectation-maximization

As the EM algorithm is guaranteed to increase the log likelihood at each iteration. If the log likelihood is concave is it guaranteed to converge to the maximum of the likelihood, that is will we get the MLE.

I am asking this in the context of using the EM algorithm to find the MLE for the Factor Model, when we assume additional probabilistic assumptions.

An extra question is whether the log likelihood of the Factor Model is concave. From reading around it seemed that finding the MLE estimate for the FM is difficult, and therefore I am not sure if the log likelihood for the FM is even concave?